# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Actions<Action>'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I noticed issue #990 but no resolution.

Project is compiling, but I'm getting a linting error saying Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Actions' in my effects and also in my components when i try to use .pipe with store. However, I don't get the issue in the same component when I use .pipe on observable.

// Linting problem example doesn't exist on type Store / Action

```
this.item$ = this.store.pipe(select(item));

@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  logout$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Logout>(AuthActionTypes.LogoutAction),
    tap(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem(USER);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    })
  );
```

// No problems

```
this.item$.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe(status => {
```

// Package.json this is Angular 6 with rxjs 6 and NgRx libraries

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing the RxJS operators? Also did you try removing `node_modules` and reinstalling the packages?

Comment: I imported using the new paths as specified on the repo and use i've cleared out that folder and reinstalled many times. project compiles...so i'm thinking maybe it's just a tslint issue?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I am doing some migration and run into this same issue. Thanks

Comment: Yeah try updating the TypeScript version

Comment: Did anyone get a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error. In my case it was because I was because I was importing Actions from '@ngrx/store-devtools/src/reducer' instead of '@ngrx/effects'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createEffect } from '@ngrx/effects';
//import { Actions } from '@ngrx/store-devtools/src/reducer'; --> wrong
import { Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import * as ProductActions from './product.actions';

    @Injectable()
    export class ProductEffects {
        constructor(private actions$: Actions,
            private productsService: ProductService) { }
    
        loadProducts$ = createEffect(() => {
            return this.actions$.pipe(
                ofType(ProductActions.loadProducts),
                mergeMap(() => this.productsService.getProducts().pipe(
                    map(products => ProductActions.loadProductsSuccess({ products }))
                ))
            )
        })
    
    }
```